# How to disable fast view option in eclipse for a plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to disable the fast view in my perspective.

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/Image211_fastview.png

I tried

```
configurer.setShowFastViewBars(false);
```

But in vain.
What should disable this bar ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding this in to the correct location?

I think you need to add it to the preWindowOpen() method of the ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class.

IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
configurer.setShowFastViewBars(false);

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I've done. but I still see the bar enabled and I can use the fast view !

Comment: which version of Eclipse are you using?